# Predict Partially matched GUIDs in SSIS parameter map

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, guid, sql-server-data-tools

For regrettable reasons, I've been tasked with automatically generating some SSIS package files. i.e. constructing the XML string representing the .dstx file.

I'm maybe 95% of the way to having achieved this and have come across a stumbling block :(

One of the tasks in the package is a "Read from Source Database" package, which binds package parameters into a SQL query.
The package parameters are declared at the top of the .dtsx file:

```
<DTS:PackageParameter
  DTS:CreationName=""
  DTS:DataType="7"
  DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
  DTS:ObjectName="LoadEndDate"
  DTS:Required="True">
  <DTS:Property
    DTS:DataType="7"
    DTS:Name="ParameterValue">12:00:00 AM</DTS:Property>
</DTS:PackageParameter>
```

and then the (two) parameters are bound to the query later on in the file:

```
name="ParameterMapping">"Parameter0:Input",{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX};"Parameter1:Input",{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX};</property>
```

*Obviously, above, I've blanked out the GUIDs to demonstrate the structure.*

I saw this, and at first glance the respective GUIDs all match up. So I implemented my code to store first GUID that I generate at the top and then re-use it for the mapping.

Unfortunately, the GUIDs don't quite match. When I open the package that I've generated, VS thinks that the SQL parameters haven't been bound. When I manually bind them in VS, then it updates the XML file with new, slightly altered GUIDs!

```
Declaration GUID: {09AFE89A-DD9F-499C-9D14-A5F937FE3B47}
Mapping GUID:     {09AFE89A-2260-499C-9D14-A5F937FE3B47}

Declaration GUID: {271E6086-3678-43A2-B5EF-DCB46DE91BA6}
Mapping GUID:     {271E6086-C987-43A2-B5EF-DCB46DE91BA6}
```

Note the 2nd block of the GUIDs!!

Does anyone have the *faintest* idea WTF is going on, or how the mapping GUID is derived from the Declaration GUID.

I will be investigating this myself this afternoon, and will post any further knowledge I glean.

---

UPDATE:

Further GUID pairs (taken from "normal" manually created packages)

```
{D8BE8459-2D2E-422D-ABD3-C7856F67CB24}
{D8BE8459-D2D1-422D-ABD3-C7856F67CB24}

{4E5A7104-3710-4DA4-8ECE-77A84838D9FA}
{4E5A7104-C8EF-4DA4-8ECE-77A84838D9FA}

{674D70A9-A68F-4BBA-BE44-7D1E3230D25E}
{674D70A9-5970-4BBA-BE44-7D1E3230D25E}

{4D7DD424-2CE4-488E-A146-44F13F2387AA}
{4D7DD424-D31B-488E-A146-44F13F2387AA}

{B6932587-FB99-4BDB-879F-E93CFD067A34}
{B6932587-0466-4BDB-879F-E93CFD067A34}

{5019F423-7DDE-422B-BF33-F9269494CBEA}
{5019F423-8221-422B-BF33-F9269494CBEA}

{7379E5EF-7D1B-4C01-9CF9-2D03F0E0702C}
{7379E5EF-82E4-4C01-9CF9-2D03F0E0702C}

{103E6151-235C-4688-9A3E-2F782B2B8611}
{103E6151-DCA3-4688-9A3E-2F782B2B8611}

{111337C4-BF81-4581-9CCE-B8C3D603D38C}
{111337C4-407E-4581-9CCE-B8C3D603D38C}

{0B1415C1-2A47-45B2-A61E-EB2F9E5F4A11}
{0B1415C1-D5B8-45B2-A61E-EB2F9E5F4A11}

{8A665C18-74BD-48A1-B270-723D83658F2D}
{8A665C18-8B42-48A1-B270-723D83658F2D}

{C2775F07-42EF-4DDB-80E5-33591C46F348}
{C2775F07-BD10-4DDB-80E5-33591C46F348}

{85242E06-D48C-47A2-BDC2-264B6D6F754A}
{85242E06-2B73-47A2-BDC2-264B6D6F754A}

{CFA3BAD6-CACB-464A-9519-D39A049678A0}
{CFA3BAD6-3534-464A-9519-D39A049678A0}
```

---

UPDATE:
The changed block doesn't appear to be dependant on the whole of the rest of the GUID:

```
{C2EB5307-CEC8-4617-BEE0-414BD875B146}
{C2EB5307-3137-4617-BEE0-414BD875B146}

{D2EB5307-CEC8-4617-BEE0-414BD875B146}
{D2EB5307-3137-4617-BEE0-414BD875B146}
```

---

UPDATE:
The changed block doesn't appear to be dependant on the rest of the file/package/project/solution.

I lifted one of the above GUIDs (with a known pairing) and pasted it in as the package parameter GUID in a completely different, completely unrelated SSIS solution. It generated the same pairing.

Comment: BIML is apparently good for autogenerating packages

Comment: If not Biml, use the object model. Writing just XML gives *me* the shudders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changed block of the GUID is the bitwise-NOT of the original value. :(

In hexadecimal, this means that each of the 4 digits is mapped: x => F - x

The *reason* that this is done, is left as an excercise to the reader.